# Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type: POJO to byte[]

Tags: java, rest, maven, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to Apache Camel. I am using REST API with Apache Camel and Spring Boot integration. I am done with get request, it is working as expected. But, I stuck with one issue while posting the data by using POST call.

I have seen bit similar error in below link. But, that doesn't help me.
[org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter available to convert from type:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46952090/org-apache-camel-notypeconversionavailableexception-no-type-converter-available)

I have tried couple of solutions available in Stackoverflow, youtube and other websites as well. But, no luck. Could you please help me to solve the problem,

**Error Description:**

> **org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type:**
>   **byte[] but has value: Bank [id=1, name=TEST, location=Bangalore] of**
>   **type: com.ta.common.bean.Bank on:**
>   Message[ID-XDNS01271-1534835668677-10-2]. Caused by: No type converter
>   available to convert from type: com.ta.common.bean.Bank to the
>   required type: byte[] with value Bank [id=1, name=TEST,
>   location=Bangalore]. Exchange[ID-XDNS01271-1534835668677-10-1]. Caused
>   by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type
>   converter available to convert from type: com.ta.common.bean.Bank to
>   the required type: byte[] with value Bank [id=1, name=TEST,
>   location=Bangalore]]  at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:117)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.DefaultNettyHttpBinding.toNettyRequest(DefaultNettyHttpBinding.java:488)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpProducer.getRequestBody(NettyHttpProducer.java:65)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyProducer.process(NettyProducer.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.NettyHttpProducer.process(NettyHttpProducer.java:56)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138)   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101)    at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectBlockingProducer.process(DirectBlockingProducer.java:53)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:181)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.processAsynchronously(ServerChannelHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.handlers.ServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(ServerChannelHandler.java:112)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.handlers.HttpServerChannelHandler.channelRead0(HttpServerChannelHandler.java:213)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.component.netty4.http.handlers.HttpServerMultiplexChannelHandler.channelRead0(HttpServerMultiplexChannelHandler.java:113)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$600(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:38)
>     at
>   io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$7.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:353)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultEventExecutor.run(DefaultEventExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>   io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
>   **Caused by:**
>   **org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException: No type converter**
>   **available to convert from type: com.ta.common.bean.Bank to the**
>   **required type: byte[] with value Bank [id=1, name=TEST,**
>   **location=Bangalore]**   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.converter.BaseTypeConverterRegistry.mandatoryConvertTo(BaseTypeConverterRegistry.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getMandatoryBody(MessageSupport.java:115)
>     ... 29 more

Camel Routing logic is as follows,

```
restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).host("localhost").port(8000);

rest("/api").consumes("application/json").post("/addbank").type(Bank.class).to("direct:addbank");

from("direct:addbank").log("request body :
 ${body}").to("netty4-http:http://localhost:8181/bank/add?bridgeEndpoint=true").throwException(new
 RuntimeException()).to("direct:cancelAdding");

 from("direct:cancelAdding").log("Cancelled adding bank details");
```

**Controller Logic Is:**

```
@RestController 

@RequestMapping(path="/bank") 

public class BankController {   

     List<Bank> bankList = new ArrayList<>();

     @PostMapping(path="/add",consumes="application/json")
     public List<Bank> addBank(@RequestBody @Valid Bank bank) {
        bankList.add(bank);         
      return bankList;  
     }
 }
```

**Bank.java:**

```
private int id;

private String name;

private String location;

//Getter & Setter methods
```

Comment: I am posting the Bank values through postman tool as a type of JSON object.

Comment: can you show your `restconfiguration()`

Comment: restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json).host("localhost").port(8000);

Comment: I don't get this error. For me the above code works. But with a little change. remove this part `.bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)` from your restconfiguration() and try. Or make it `RestBindingMode.auto`. Which version of camel are you using?

Comment: camel-core-2.22.0

Comment: @pvpkiran, Thank you so much. removing .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json) solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not exactly reproduce the error with the above code. hoeever when I tried the above code , this is the exception I got.

> org.apache.camel.processor.binding.BindingException: Cannot bind to
>   json as message body is not json compatible.
>   Exchange[ID-DESKTOP-OS0TDG5-1534851950401-0-1]

Fix for this is to 
Change rest configuration from

```
 restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").host("localhost").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)....;
```

to

```
 restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").host("localhost").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)....;
```

or you can omit bindingmode altogether.

Comment: I have tried with RestBindingMode.auto. But, I faced the same issue. I have removed bindingMode() completely. It started working. Thanks again.